# Minimum distance between a point and hypersphere

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

Given $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$:

1. what is the formula (or algorithm) for finding a hypersphere $S$ with a minimum radius $r$ that can contain all the $n$ points?
2. And, how to calculate the minimum Euclidean distance between point $p$, located outside of $S$, and $S$?

(I'm assuming that when $p$ is inside or on $S$ the distance is 0.)

I'm not particularly knowledgeable about the concepts related to high-dimensional objects, so sorry for possible mistakes or ambiguity.

Any bits of help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Hassan

Answer (score 2):

These Wikipedia pages should be useful:

[Smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)

[Bounding sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Algorithms)